# What is the difference between Float32, Float32LE and Float32MLE?

Tags: floating-point, abstract-data-type, scada

I'm working in a SCADA system with Modbus protocol. It offers me these data types and I don't know what's the difference between them. Could anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

**`Float32`** or sometimes `Float32BE` is the default representation of a float value by using ***big endian***. For a float with 32 bits (which is typically encoded by using the *IEEE 754 standard*) we need 4 bytes which leads to the following memory layout:
`Byte 1`, `Byte 2`, `Byte 3`, `Byte 4` or `ABCD` (to use a more common and readable example with 4 different characters).

**`Float32LE`** stands for ***little endian*** and is represented in the following memory layout:
`Byte 4`, `Byte 3`, `Byte 2`, `Byte 1` or `DCBA`

**`Float32MLE`** stands for ***mid-little-endian*** and is represented in the following memory layout:
`Byte 3`, `Byte 4`, `Byte 1`, `Byte 2` or `CDAB`

To complete the list of possibilities you can also find something called
**`Float32MBE`** which is ***mid-big-endian*** and represented in the following memory layout:
`Byte 2`, `Byte 1`, `Byte 3`, `Byte 4` or `BACD`